# Direct product of quotient groups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, group-isomorphism

Let $ G $ is a finite solvable group, Suppose $ H $ and $ N $ are minimal normal subgroups of $ G $. Then $ G/N \times G/H \cong G/N\cap H $ ?

Comment: I suggest you experiment with some small examples. Try groups of order $8$ for example.

Comment: This result is obviously false in the case $N=H$.

Comment: What is a *minimal* normal subgroup? $1$ is normal.

Comment: @Bernard $ N $ is minimal normal subgroup if exist normal subgroup $ S $ of $ G $ that $ S \leq N \leq G $, Then $ N= S $ or $ S = 1 $.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is false.

If $N=H$ you have $$G/H \times G/H \cong G/H$$
which is not possible for groups whose order is not prime ($G/H$ is not trivial and is finite).

In the case that $N \neq H$ you have by minimality that $N \cap H = 1$. Now, it is quite easy to see that
$$G/N \times G/H \cong G/1 =G$$
implies that $$|N||H|=|G|$$

Recall the lemma

> If $H \subset G$ is a minimal normal subgroup, then $H$ is a $p$-group for some prime $p$.

This implies that $|G|$ has at most two prime factors. So, every solvable group whose order has at least 3 prime factors forms a counterexample to what you said.